# Error while compiling Ruby (RVM)

Tags: ruby, rvm

OS : Ubuntu 12.04

Ruby : 1.9.3

I'd want to install Ruby with RVM but when I type:

```
$> rvm install ruby
```

I have an error while compiling:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libX11.a(CrGlCur.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/libX11.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/tcltklib.so] Erreur 1
make[2]: quittant le répertoire « /home/lingla_j/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ext/tk »
make[1]: *** [ext/tk/all] Erreur 2
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /home/lingla_j/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 »
make: *** [build-ext] Erreur 2
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: For Ruby it is the last version 1.9.3 i'm trying to install with RVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are compiling ruby against static version of libraries, this could happen in rather few rare cases.

Make sure you read `rvm requirements` and install all required libraries.

Check your RVM configuration files for compilation switches:

```
cat /etc/rvmrc ~/.rvmrc
```

And finally reinstall ruby to make sure clean installation is done:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

As a note right now it's equivalent to `rvm install ruby` as 1.9.3 is the latest version of ruby.

Answer (score -1):

you can install rvm by bash 
`bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)`